# The compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project - Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]Today I've imported a Maven project in my eclipse. When I try to go for Auto suggest, when I was adding some code, it alerts me as "The compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project". I saw few workarounds for this issue, but none of them solved. What should be done for this one?

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.core.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>Softpro</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>cu-softpro-connector</artifactId>
<name>jar :: cu-softpro-connector</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-softpro-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-svcframework-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-shared</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-common-entity</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-services-base</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.core.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>cu-subsystems</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-platform-model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>cu-forms-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I guess this is a multi-module maven project. If you want to open a class of a module you need to open the class in the `sub-module` not in `parent->sub-module`. You can check the icon of the editor. If it's a solid `J` then it's correct. If it's a framed `J` you oen the class at the wrong place.

Comment: @SubOptimal, few auto suggestion is working and few are not working.. For eg, Syso -> System.out.println is coming now, where as if I want to see the methods of the objects, even after pressing ctrl + space, methods are not coming

Comment: the explanation for this is that `System` and its methods are part of Java SE

Comment: What structure does your project have? Do you see the solid `J` on the editor tab? Auto-completion of `syso` is an Eclipse editor thing. If your class is not found it's an classpath related thing. Are your sources below `src/main/java`. What is your directory structure? You should add more information.

Comment: @SubOptimal, uploaded the screen shot of Java classes.

Comment: please post your `pom.xml`

Comment: did you use the m2e plugin? I guess no

Comment: @Ulrich, updated with pom.xml

Comment: Can you see in your screenshot that it's a framed `J` you need to open the files from a different path. As I said already.

Comment: @SubOptimal, How can I open them in different path? I didn't understand what you said

Comment: your screenshot indicates that you are working with a multi module project, as @Syed already assumed. How did you import it to eclipse?

Comment: Have a look at `http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm`.

Comment: @Ulrich, as normal fashion only File->import-> Existing maven projects, then point to the folder where it is located.

Comment: @SubOptimal, the topic isn't available

Comment: try [this](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm?cp=1_4_12)

Comment: @SubOptimal, what should be done for this fix?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with the maven project when I imported.

**Root Cause:**

I Searched the file by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+R** and open the file on  the path on the **Parent -> Sub-module -> FileName.java**.So while pressing Ctrl+Space it was giving the error **The compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project - Maven**

**Solution:**

We need to make sure that we are opening the file on the submodule path and also the build path should be configure to the proper jdk installed in your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a multi-module Maven project in Eclipse you see in the `project explorer` normally

```
- parent-module
  - sub-module1
    - src
      - main
        - java
          - YourClass <-- the one with the framed J icon
  + sub-module2
- sub-module1
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - YourClass <-- the one with the solid J icon
```

framed J icon [image]
solid J icon [image]

Icons are explained at http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm.

To import a Maven project into Eclipse follow this documentation[Importing Maven Projects](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html).

Comment: All my sub modules are having same icon

Comment: Tell me the correct process of importing Maven project, I've downloaded the project from SVN and stored them in E drive, and my workspace is in F drive

Comment: @Syed I added a link with a description. You need the m2e plugin and then the project must be imported as described at the link. Maybe at this step there was a mistake.

Comment: I can't open that link as its blocked here

Comment: @Syed Than search in the internet for `importing maven projects into eclipse`.