# Source Generate Getters and Setters

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I've been getting a weird error when I try to use eclipse to generate getters and setters.  I left clicked, then clicked on source then on generate getters and setters.  I, however get an error that says:

> The resource is not on the build path of a Java project

It's weird as it seems to be working for my other projects.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464998/eclipse-the-resource-is-not-on-the-build-path-of-a-java-project

Comment: Maybe you open the Java file from the wrong location. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803889/the-compilation-unit-is-not-on-the-build-path-of-a-java-project-maven/37804998#37804998 and check if the file is displayed with a solid or framed `J` icon.

Comment: does this duplicated linked question has really something to with the setter getters here???